# Display results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I posted earlier and this is an extenstion of my old question. 
I have a several users in my db and each will add their results.  I need a way of taking each of these results and displaying them all (for all results from all users) into a table.  I tried something like:

```
<% Result.find(:all) do |result| %>
  <%= result.name %>
<% end %>
```

where name is a field in the model Result and that did not display anything.  Any ideas into how to do that.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Please note that `find(:all)` is deprecated. Use `Result.all`

Answer (score 2):

Hey, you missed `each`

```
<% Result.find(:all).each do |result| %>
  <%= result.name %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% Result.all.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.name %>
<% end %>
```

Update

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <% Result.all.each do |result| %>
      <td><%= result.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But it still giving me the same output as Result.find(:all). Any ideas why?

Comment: Your `results` table is empty, or `name` field is blank for every result

Comment: @ali: do you have any records in results table? then you will get `[]` for Result.all..you can see this by `<% puts Result.all.inspect %>` and see the log or console.

Comment: Thats not right.  When I put Result.all in my console I can see data for name.

Comment: Plenty of data in there.  Not sure whats going on

Comment: @ali..can you post what you see when you do `Result.all` in console.

Comment: @ali..also make sure you have given `=` in `<%= result.name %>`

Comment: [#<Result id: 22, equipment_id: 10, name:Ali, kit: "batch", batch_number: 243, created_at: "2011-03-31 11:21:57", updated_at: "2011-03-31 11:21:57">]

Comment: I was working on my console and for some reason it kept on giving me the :all results.  But when I tried it in my /views/results/index file it worked.

Comment: Guys, one last question.  When I put <%= result.name %> I get four names like this: Ali John Martin Chris.  I want to put these in a table, so split these names into columns.  Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: duh! i didnt know it will be that simple

Answer (score 1):

You have forget to call `each`

```
<% Result.all.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.name %>
<% end %>
```